# How can I save someone's profile icon in Discord?

Tags: discord

I want to save the profile image of a user in Discord. I've tried viewing their profile, but I can't find a way to save the image.

**Is there a way to save a user's profile picture in Discord?**

[image]

Answer (score 13):

1. Open the profile of the user who has the profile picture you want AKA, clicking on their profile and pressing "View Profile"
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+I to open the inspect window (if you're using discord on your browser you can also Right Click their profile picture then Inspect Element
3. Press the button at the top left of the inspect window (should be a square with a mouse in it) and with that tool click their profile picture
4. Copy the now present url in the inspect window from quote to quote with ctrl+c then paste it into your browser. There might be a little trouble in this part, I found that you could click on a part that's not highlighted but still in the code of the element (AKA, anywhere in style=), and then highlighting the url by holding down click instead of double-clicking and then highlighting to save time (If you double-click, it'll just highlight the entire thing and not the url).
5. You now have their profile picture! From here you can save it like any other image.
6. (Optional) If you feel the image is too small, at the end of the url replace "128" with "2048" (without the quotes) then press enter, and do step 5.

Source/Credits (Yes, I know I just copied the entire thing and edited some small parts to make it seem more understandable):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvpoNnyafeQ

Comment: This is no longer true. However you can dump the contents of the cache using [Discord Cache Dump](https://github.com/uintdev/Discord-Cache-Dump)

Comment: On mac its ⌃⌘I (Option-Command-I) https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-using-finders-get-info-and-inspector-windows

And yes, it *does* still work (at least on mac)

Answer (score 3):

It's easier than you might think.

Under Linux open the following folder: `~/.config/discord/Cache` - That's it.

That folder contains EVERY single media file you ever received or sent on discord, including profile pictures.

Note: When a person changes their profile picture, the old ones still persist in that folder.

Comment: How do you identify what's what? It's just a bunch of hex strings and the files are all binary blobs.

Comment: @AaronFranke My Answer is three years old. Three years ago, you identify it by either looking at the Thumbnails if your File manager has them supported/enabled or you open the folder with your favorite image viewer and go through it.

Comment: Just tried this in Dolphin. It doesn't generate any thumbnails. The file command says it's a binary file and Okular can't open it either. I have over 7k files in there! Is there anything I can do with them besides deleting them?

Comment: @Joe Apparently now it's encoded, three years ago that wasn't the case. I'd try to inspect one such file, maybe its just base64 encoded or something like that. If it's actually encrypted then you'll have to do some more reverse-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

c:/users/(user)/appdata/temp and you should find a folder called dir and a bunch of numbers. profile pictures are in there for some reason

Comment: The question is about a user in Discord. I believe that such a person will typically be remote, and not have a login/account on the OP’s system.

Comment: @Scott No, he is correct. Discord caches the profile pictures of your friends (and non-friends!) in that folder. Discord saves every profile picture of every person you ever came in contact with, and does never delete them, even if a person updates a profile picture the old one still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Through the discord website you can view the profile, then open the dev window by pressing ctrl+shift+i then you can click the square with the cursor at the top left then highlight the profile picture. Once you have clicked on the profile picture in the select mode, it will highlight the html for that picture, in the  tag you will see a link, which you can copy and pate into a new tab and copy or save the image.