# How do you save a discord users pfp?

Tags: discord

A similar question has been asked before however, due to discord updates the answer is out dated and no longer applicable.
[How can I save someone's profile icon in Discord?](https://superuser.com/questions/1235262/how-can-i-save-someones-profile-icon-in-discord)

Answer (score 0):

As there is now a "previously known as" icon next to most people's profiles, you can once again fairly easily grab the image for most users. (this is a bot, so there is a {/} instead of a # but it's the same concept)
[image: spot to right click]
First, right click on the small icon next to the picture to access the context menu; select Inspect.

[image: chrome dev tools]
In dev tools, one line will be automatically highlighted. Go up three lines from there, to the first closed  container. Open this by hitting the arrow to reveal sub-elements, and keep opening subsequent sub-elements until you hit the bottom.

[image: dev tools with the file highlighted]
The link you find there will give you the image for the person's profile picture. If you change the "size" at the end, you may even be able to get a higher resolution version; try doubling the number or using various powers of two

Answer (score -1):

no there is not but they can send you the file of the image in the chat or even ask them what words they searched on google